# How does variable setting work with await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, scope

Can someone explain to me why this is not working the way I am expecting?

I am expecting the last console.log to run after my functions run, but it is returning empty length string instead of the actual date.

These are the variables I want to set after my function call. Declaring them now so the scope is set globally.

```
var seasonStart = '';
var seasonID = '';
```

This function gets my json data. I have URL declared above in my code, its returning everything as expected.

```
async function getCurrentSeasonapi(url) {

  //store response
  const response = await fetch(url);

  //store data in JSON
  var data = await response.json();
  //I tried to set the variables here but it didn't work so I tried using a separate function
  setSeasonInfo(data);
}
```

The function that is called above:

```
//set current season
function setSeasonInfo(data) {
   seasonStart = data.seasons[0].regularSeasonStartDate;
   seasonID = data.seasons[0].seasonId;
   //this returns the correct date
   console.log(seasonStart);
}
```

calling the function, so my variables should be set correctly after this function runs

```
getCurrentSeasonapi(getCurrentSeasonURL);

//this is returning '' instead of the actual date set in the function
console.log(seasonStart);
```

I'm thinking this is a scope issue but I'm not sure why.
Here is an example that I was testing the scope out on. This is how I was expecting my code to run:

```js
var test = 1;
async function changeTest() {
    test =100;
}
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = test + `<br>` + 'Run Function:' + `<br>`;
changeTest();
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML += test
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p> testing JS execution</p>

<div id = 'first'>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not a scope issue. Where is the `await` where you do `getCurrentSeasonapi(getCurrentSeasonURL)`

Comment: Your last example with the async test does not prove the point since there is nothing asynchronous about it.

Comment: In the second code block (after the variables) I set the async function getCurrentSeasonapi. This block has the awaits in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not awaiting the call. The example code should have a promise in it.

```js
var testSync = 1;
var testAsync = 1;
async function changeTest() {
  testSync = 100;
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      testAsync = 100;
      resolve();
    }, 300);
  });
}

document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = `${testSync} - ${testAsync} <br> Running <br>`;
changeTest();
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML += `${testSync} - ${testAsync}`
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p> testing JS execution</p>

  <div id='first'>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Now with it awaiting the call

```js
var testSync = 1;
var testAsync = 1;
async function changeTest() {
  testSync = 100;
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      testAsync = 100;
      resolve();
    }, 300);
  });
}


(async function() {
  document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = `${testSync} - ${testAsync} <br> Running <br>`;
  await changeTest();
  document.getElementById("first").innerHTML += `${testSync} - ${testAsync}`
}());
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p> testing JS execution</p>

  <div id='first'>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This kind of makes sense. I can see where my example is wrong. I guess my question was more of a why isnt my code working the same way as the example?
I tried applying your fix to my example to my actual code, but it is still returning ''

Comment: So you did `await getCurrentSeasonapi(getCurrentSeasonURL);`?

Comment: Tried it again and its working now. I think I changed something else when I tried earlier.
THANKS!!!